# Javascript program working the opposite way?

Tags: javascript

So, I am a beginner javascript scripter, in my course, my tutor gave me an assignment to make a program that can find the greatest of 3 numbers, but , for some reason, it works the opposite way, finding the lowest number. Me and my tutor have been trying to find what is wrong for the past hour, with basically no success.

We used 10, 15, 8 as inputs respectively, and 8, 15, 10  respectively, and have received the same result, 8 being the greatest, for some reason.

If anybody can at least identify the issue with the code, that would be great.

Please note that the program isn't fully working, I am not done with the part were if 2 numbers are equal to each other.

-Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="input">
    <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
    <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
    <input id="num3" type="text" name="num3">
    <input value="Find Greatest Number" type="button" name="submit" onClick="compare()" id="button">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function compare(){
            var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value
            var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value
            var num3 = document.getElementById('num3').value
console.log("number 1 " + num1)
console.log("number 2 " + num2)
console.log("number 3 " + num3)


            if ( num1 > num3 && num1 > num2) { //num1 greatest
                console.log("Number 1, " + num1 + " is the greatest number")
            }
            else if ( num2 > num3 && num2 > num1) { //num2 greatest
                console.log("Number 2, " + num2 + " is the greatest number")
            }
            else if ( num3 > num1 && num3 > num2) { //num3 greatest
                console.log("Number 3, " + num3 + " is the greatest number") 
            }
            else if (num2 == num3 && num2 == num1) { //num 2 equal
                console.log("All numbers are equal")
            }
            else if (num3 == num2 && num3 == num1) { //num 3 equal
                console.log("All numbers are equal")
            }
            else if (num1 == num2 && num1 == num3) { //num 1 equal
                console.log("All numbers are equal")
            }
            else if (num1 == num2 && num1 > num3) { //nums 1 and 2 greatest
                console.log("Numbers " + num1 + " and " + num2 + "are the greatest numbers" )
            }
            else if (num3 == num2 && num3 > num1) { //nums 3 and 2 greatest
                console.log("Numbers " + num3 + " and " + num2 + "are the greatest numbers" )
            }
            else if (num1 == num3 && num1 > num3) { //nums 1 and 3 greatest
                console.log("Numbers " + num1 + " and " + num2 + "are the greatest numbers" )
            }
            else {
                console.log("An error has occured. ")
            }


        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should parse the value using either parseInt or parseFloat before comparing

Comment: FYI, [`Math.max(num1, num2, num3)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Comment: One error I saw right now:

            else if (num1 == num3 && num1 > num3) { //nums 1 and 3 greatest

Comment: Also, if a == b, then b == a, according to basic math. Your three checks for equality are thus redundant.

Comment: AngelSalazar is probably right on the money - your variables are all strings, and with > and == you are doing string comparison, not numerical comparison.

Also, you should be doing what Phil is suggesting, rather than writing this spaghetti code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, javascript gets user's input from html as a `string`. So you have to convert to to `int` before you perform mathematical calculations or comparisons.

You can either use: `var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);`

or a shorthand: `var num1 = +document.getElementById('num1').value`